# Azure DevOps agent cannot find local certificate

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a powershell script that we can run, and it works fine.

We try to run the script from the agent, and it fails saying it can't find the path because it does not exist.

The script in question is:

```
function AddIisUserPrivateKeyReadOnlyAccess($certPath, $appPoolName)
{
    $cert = Get-ChildItem $certPath
    $pkFile = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($cert).Key.UniqueName
    # Private keys are in one of two paths, if statement below tests if the key is in this path
    $pkFullFilePath = "$env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\$pkFile"
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $pkFullFilePath))
    {
        # If that path doesn't have private key file, it must be here
        $pkFullFilePath = "$env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\$pkFile"
    }
    $pkAcl = Get-Acl -Path $pkFullFilePath
    $iisReadOnlyAccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS AppPool\$appPoolName", "Read", "Allow")
    # ReseAccessRule adds access rule and overwrites any other access rules for that account
    $pkAcl.ResetAccessRule($iisReadOnlyAccessRule)
    Set-Acl $pkFullFilePath $pkAcl
}
# HTTPS cert is installed to LocalMachine in both Personal and TrustedPeople stores
$httpCertMyPath = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\‎‎$(HttpsCertThumbprint)"
AddIisUserPrivateKeyReadOnlyAccess -certPath $httpCertMyPath -appPoolName $(IISAppPoolName)
$httpCertTrustedPeoplePath = "Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPeople\$(HttpsCertThumbprint)"
AddIisUserPrivateKeyReadOnlyAccess -certPath $httpCertTrustedPeoplePath -appPoolName $(IISAppPoolName)
```

It fails inside if `AddIisUserPrivateKeyReadOnlyAccess` on this line: `$cert = Get-ChildItem $certPath` with this error:

[image: azure failure]

We have taken this script and put it as a local script on the same machine the agent is running on and run it manually and it works great. It just won't run from the pipeline.

Could anyone help us troubleshoot why, please?

Comment: Based on the error, I would try `Set-Location Cert:` prior to the get-childitem

Comment: @DougMaurer -- tried that, it didn't work. We tried hard-coding the path, upper case, lower case... nothing is working. I guess we manually run the script instead of the agent doing it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Are you sure the agent that is running is actually a local agent and not hosted? You could be using the wrong agent pool. In your script add `Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;] Agent running on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)"` as a sanity check and see what machine. Also output `$PSScriptRoot` to see the location of the script. I see the script is running on the `D:` drive, which is usually the hosted agent. Where did you install the agent on the local machine? The default for local installs usually ends up at `C:\agent`

Comment: @AlexKwitny -- That's a great lead! We are going to pick this back up on Monday and we will give that a shot. Totally makes sense. Will let you know.

Comment: @Andy you'll want to check your `project settings>agent pools` and see where your local agent is. Then you go to your pipeline and on the tasks, the pipeline task, you choose your agent pool there. I suspect that's your issue. If you have multiple local agents in that same pool, you'll want to ensure your phases include a "Demand" requiring the specific agent. `Agent.ComputerName` for the name and the value being your server OR a variable (i.e. `$(MyServer)`. I prefer a variable so I can have the same variable in different groups and depending on the group you link it'll change environments.